# Understanding the solution to this exercise on Gödel's second incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

Exercise:

> Show that if $F$ is a closed formula and if
> $$\mathcal{P} \vdash \exists v_0\; Drv[ \underline{\#F},v_0]\Rightarrow F,$$
> then $$\mathbb{P}\vdash F.$$

Solution:

> Suppose that
> $$\mathcal{P} \vdash \exists v_0\; Drv[ \underline{\#F},v_0]\Rightarrow F,$$
> then by taking the contrapositive,
> $$\mathcal{P} \vdash \lnot F \Rightarrow \lnot \exists v_0\; Drv[ \underline{\#F},v_0],$$
> equivalently,
> $$\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} \vdash  \lnot \exists v_0\; Drv[ \underline{\#F},v_0].$$
> But $\lnot \exists v_0\; Drv[ \underline{\#F},v_0]$ means that $F$ is not derivable in $\mathcal{P}$, in other words, that $\mathcal{P}\cup \lnot F$ is a consistent theory. So we have
> $$\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} \vdash Con(\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\},$$
> which implies, according to Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, that $\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\}$ is not a consistent theory; hence $\mathcal{P}\vdash F$.

I don't understand why suddenly we have
$$\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} \vdash Con(\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\}.$$
Could you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but can you tell me what $\mathcal{P}$ is? (My guess is any consistent extension of Robinson's arithmetic, but I'm not certain).

Comment: @user400188 $\mathcal{P}$ is the first order Peano axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that "$\neg\exists v_0 Drv[\underline{\# F}, v_0]$" is equivalent to "$Con(\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\})$:" intuitively, $\mathcal{P}$ fails to prove $F$ iff $\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}$ is consistent.

This equivalence is provable in a very weak system, e.g. $\mathcal{P}$ itself.

A bit more precisely, we're combining the sequent $$\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}\vdash \neg\exists v_0 Drv[\underline{\# F}, v_0]$$ which we've gotten from the argument so far and the sequent $$\mathcal{P}\vdash \neg\exists v_0 Drv[\underline{\#F}, v_0]\leftrightarrow Con(\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\})$$ which holds in general.

Comment: I find this difficult to understand intuitively. Because, while $\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} \vdash \lnot \exists v_0 Drv[\underline{\#F},v_0]$ means that $F$ is not derivable, $\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} \vdash Con(\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\}$ is the exact contrary of $\mathcal{P}\cup \{\lnot F\} $ being consistent.

Comment: @Jiu No, the whole expression "$\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}\vdash\neg\exists v_0 Drv[\underline{\#F},v_0]$" means that **the theory $\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}$ proves that** $F$ is not $\mathcal{P}$-derivable. Remember, "$X$ proves that $y$" does *not* mean "$y$ is the case," and in fact "$F$ is not $\mathcal{P}$-derivable" is exactly what we're trying to *disprove* by contradiction! (Basically, we're trying to show that $\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}$ is wrong.)

Comment: You are right of course.

Comment: Since I cannot use intuition here, I will have to prove the last sequent in your answer. Is it evident to prove, as the solution in my book seems to suggest?

Comment: @Jiu I'd say so. The basic idea is the following. "$Con(\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\})$" is just shorthand for "$\neg\exists v_1 Drv'[\underline{\#\perp}, v_1]$" where "$Drv'$" is the derivability relation for the theory $\mathcal{P}\cup\{\neg F\}$ and "$\perp$" is the logical constant for contradiction *(if you prefer you could use "$0=1$" or similar)*. So you're trying to prove, in $\mathcal{P}$, the sentence $$\neg\exists v_0Drv[\underline{\#F},v_0]\leftrightarrow\neg\exists v_1Drv'[\underline{\#\perp},v_1].$$ Really, you're **proving an instance of the deduction theorem inside $\mathcal{P}$**.

Comment: I think if it's not clear how to proceed on this point, it would be worth asking a separate question about it (since this comment thread is getting a bit long).

Comment: Thanks you! I will try to work this out. It's just that the rephrasing in the solution is really confusing.